# Creating multiple copies of same database from a single Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, database, entity-framework

I am creating a shopping application, which has many branches with different names.

I am using Entity Framework in my WPF project, I am able to create a single database from my entity model.

If my entity name is `JIMS`, a database with name `JIMS` is created. But I also want to create a new database in SQL Server using the same Entity Framework model with a different name for a different branch.

So that the user can select the branch and there will be a separate database for it?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a method return the database you want to connect to an pass it into the constructor of your instance of DbContext

```
public class YourContext : DbContext
{
  public YourContext(string targetDatabase)
  {
      this.Database.Connection.ChangeDatabase(targetDatabase);
  }
}
```

Comment: But I also want to create the database 'JIMSEntities.CreateDatabase()' for the first time.

Comment: By default CreateDatabase will create database with name JIMS